# Use of both easy and multi interfaces in libcurl for FTP

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl

I'm writing a program that continuously and recursively checks an FTP server for new files. When a file is detected, it is downloaded.

I wrote the all thing using the curl easy interface, since blocking calls to `curl_easy_perform()` are great for the control channel and listing operations. But when it comes to download files, the multi interface seems a lot more appropriate. I thought about switching the entire thing to multi, but it gets very complicated for directory listing.

So here's my question, can I use both interfaces, easy and multi inside the same thread ? If so, can they share the same connection to the server ?

**EDIT 1**

Instead of using `curl_easy_perform()`, is there a way to check for a single transfer status ? So I could use the curl_multi_* interface for all my transfers, and only check my LIST command status right after I perform it. This would allow me to simulate a blocking behavior, without interfering with my file transfers that would be handled and checked elsewhere.

From what I saw, the [curl_multi_info_read()](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html) doesn't allow to do so :

> When you fetch a message using this function, it is removed from the internal queue so calling this function again will not return the same message again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question:

> When an easy handle is setup and ready for transfer, then instead of using curl_easy_perform like when using the easy interface for transfers, you should add the easy handle to the multi handle with curl_multi_add_handle. You can add more easy handles to a multi handle at any point, even if other transfers are already running.

From [libcurl - multi interface overview](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) (ONE MULTI HANDLE MANY EASY HANDLES)

Comment: Not really. What I'd like to achieve would be to run `curl_multi_perform()` for my file transfers AND `curl_easy_perform()` for my control transfers (mostly LIST commands). I actually need to keep the blocking behavior of `curl_easy_perform()` for directory listing.

Comment: @agfline but why? subsequent LIST commands could be done while the previous kicked off transfers are still transferring, right?

Comment: Yes, but my main loop is actually a function called inside a while loop. This function iterates over each file, in each FTP directory, and returns one file at a time to the while loop. To do that, the function has multiple blocking call to `curl_easy_perform()` to perform directory listing, retrieve file sizes... That's why, switching over `curl_multi_perform()` seems a bit overkill to me, from the perspective of an FTP control channel. Or maybe I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

> can I use both interfaces, easy and multi inside the same thread ?

yes absolutely, but note that the easy api is mostly blocking, and the multi api is mostly non-blocking, so if you combine them wrong, you might end up in a situation where your multi transfers are hanging/slow because your thread is blocking on a curl_easy~ call.

> If so, can they share the same connection to the server ?

strictly speaking, yes, at least in some situations, but you really should let libcurl worry about connection-reuse details, unless you're in a micro-optimization phase (and given your questions, you're absolutely not)

> is there a way to check for a single transfer status

check status of a single transfer from a curl_multi list of transfers?
idk to be honest, when i use curl_multi, i usually only check up on them when they're no longer active as reported by curl_multi_info_read() & co.. you could wrap each transfer in its own object with its own dedicated download thread, and keep track of each transfer with CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION & co,

this program will output

```
transfer #1 is 4.70178% downloaded. running: true
transfer #2 is 6.51742% downloaded. running: true
transfer #3 is 6.14288% downloaded. running: true
transfer #4 is 6.01199% downloaded. running: true
transfer #0 is 12.3027% downloaded. running: true
transfer #1 is 8.73407% downloaded. running: true
transfer #2 is 14.0515% downloaded. running: true
transfer #3 is 12.8638% downloaded. running: true
transfer #4 is 11.8516% downloaded. running: true
(...)
transfer #0 is 94.8156% downloaded. running: true
transfer #1 is 88.5291% downloaded. running: true
transfer #2 is 98.8117% downloaded. running: true
transfer #3 is 92.01% downloaded. running: true
transfer #4 is 100% downloaded. running: false
transfer #0 is 100% downloaded. running: false
transfer #1 is 100% downloaded. running: false
transfer #2 is 100% downloaded. running: false
transfer #3 is 100% downloaded. running: false
```

it keeps track of each individual transfer in its own thread, and the main thread can easily check up on any individual transfers by doing transfers[x]->status ~

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include <curl/curl.h>

class Curl_Transfer
{
public:
    std::string url;
    std::string response_headers;
    std::string response_body;
    CURL *ch = nullptr;
    CURLcode curl_easy_perform_code = CURLcode(0);
    bool running = true;
    std::thread dedicated_thread;
    int64_t expected_size = 0; // << content-length reported size

    Curl_Transfer(std::string url) : url(url)
    {
        this->dedicated_thread = std::thread([&]() -> void
                                             {
                                                 this->ch = curl_easy_init();
                                                 curl_easy_setopt(this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, this->url.c_str());
                                                 curl_easy_setopt(this->ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,
                                                                  this);
                                                 curl_easy_setopt(this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADERDATA,
                                                                  this);
                                                 curl_easy_setopt(this->ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, this->WRITEFUNCTION_cb);
                                                 curl_easy_setopt(this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, this->HEADERFUNCTION_cb);
                                                 CURLcode code=curl_easy_perform(this->ch);
                                                 //std::cout << "code: " << code << std::endl;
                                                 this->curl_easy_perform_code = code;
                                                 this->running = false;
                                             });
    }
    ~Curl_Transfer()
    {
        std::cout << "DESTRUCTING!" << std::endl;
        this->dedicated_thread.join();
        curl_easy_cleanup(this->ch);
    }

private:
    // this function need to be static to be compatible with some C->C++ calling stuff... idk, but it also need access to this, so fthis=this...
    static size_t WRITEFUNCTION_cb(const char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, Curl_Transfer *fthis)
    {
        CURL *ch = fthis->ch;
        fthis->response_body.append(data, size * nmemb);
        //std::cout << "got body data! " << size*nmemb << "\n";
        return size * nmemb;
    };
    // this function need to be static to be compatible with some C->C++ calling stuff... idk, but it also need access to this, so fthis=this...
    static size_t HEADERFUNCTION_cb(const char *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, Curl_Transfer *fthis)
    {
        CURL *ch = fthis->ch;
        //std::cout << "got headers! " << size*nmemb << "\n";
        fthis->response_headers.append(data, size * nmemb);
        std::string_view svd(data, size * nmemb);
        const std::string_view needle = "Content-Length: ";
        auto clp = svd.find(needle);
        if (clp != std::string::npos)
        {
            svd = svd.substr(needle.size());
            std::string fck(svd);
            fthis->expected_size = std::stoll(fck, nullptr, 0);
        }
        return size * nmemb;
    };
};
int main()
{
    curl_global_init(~0); // << todo get proper constant
    std::vector<Curl_Transfer *> transfers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        auto fck = new Curl_Transfer("http://speedtest.tele2.net/100MB.zip");
        transfers.push_back((fck));
    }
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < transfers.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "transfer #" << i << " is " << (double((transfers[i]->response_body.size()) / double(transfers[i]->expected_size))*100) << "% downloaded. running: " << (transfers[i]->running ? "true" : "false") << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

- there's probably a better way to do this though.. there has to be. but until someone smarter comes along, *this works at least...
- apparently i did all the threading shit to avoid using the curl_multi api.. dafuq
- you're using C, not C++... sorry, ofc you can do all of the above in C as well, but i'm not comfortable enough with C to enjoy re-writing that in C (anyone is free to re-write the code in C if they want to)

Comment: Thank you. When I associate an easy handler with a multi handler using `curl_multi_add_handle()`, then I can't use `curl_easy_perform()` on it. When I do, curl debug says : _easy handle already used in multi handle_. On the other hand, when I don't associate an easy handler with the multi one it works fine, however curl doesn't share the connection between the two handlers and opens a new one for each...

Comment: @agfline why do you care about the tcp connection reuse though? are the tcp connections expensive somehow?

Comment: Because I've got to deal with proprietary servers with very small max client _(control connections)_ allowed. When I run my program, the control channel connection says `220-You are user number 54 of 150 allowed.`, then when I start downloading a file it says `220-You are user number 12 of 150 allowed.`. So my understanding is that each connection uses a different control channel and that might be a problem regarding this server limit. Note that I'm not currently running tests against the production servers that's why it says _150 allowed_.

Comment: @agfline i think you should just set a limit to max 150 concurrent downloads and enable CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE to make sure a completed curl download always close the connection asap, rather than fine-tune your curl code to re-use connections so the total connections is <=150 =/